# How to build authenticationendpoint and accountrecoveryendpoint in <apim-home>/repository/deployment/server/webapps

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed WSO2 API manager4.0.0 All-in-one on the vm. I found some wars and folders but i don't know where were they from, like authenticationendpoint and accountrecoveryendpoint, How to build them and which tag should I use ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `accountrecoveryendpoint` and `authenticationendpoint` webapps are obtained from the `identity-apps` repo [1]. The identity-apps version used in API-M 4.0.0 is `1.0.558` [2].

The `accountrecoveryendpoint` webapp can be obtained by building the `recovery-portal` directory [3] and the `authenticationendpoint` webapp can be obtained by building the `authentication-portal` directory [4].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps

[2] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v4.0.0/pom.xml#L1312

[3] https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/tree/v1.0.558/apps/recovery-portal

[4] https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/tree/v1.0.558/apps/authentication-portal